# Shell command with option dont work with Python Popen (shell=True)

Tags: python, shell, solaris, popen

I am trying to shell execute commands with options using Popen in python 2.6.8.
I noticed that I am unable to do so using the shell=True. However, the default case (shell by default is False) works fine.

Here is the `shell=True` code:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> 
>>> 
>>> p = subprocess.Popen(['ls','-l'],shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> o = p.communicate()[0]
>>> o
'cmd.py\ncmd.py.~1~\ncmd.pyc'
```

Here is the same `ls -l` without `shell=True`:

```
    >>> p1 = subprocess.Popen(['ls','-l'],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    >>> o1 = p1.communicate()[0]
    >>> o1
    'total 27218
-rwxrwxrwx   1 bkaithpa staff       3660 Jan 15 17:05 cmd.py
-rwxrwxrwx   1 bkaithpa staff       3660 Jun  6  2013 cmd.py.~1~
-rwxrwxrwx   1 bkaithpa staff       4139 Jun  6  2013 cmd.pyc
    >>>
```

Does anyone know why this is the case ??

Comment: you shouldn't use *shell=True* anyway, because it can lead to unpredictable behaviour. The '-l' is interpreted by the shell and so it's ignored.

Comment: thanks you.... I will make sure I dont use shell=True to avoid shell injection attacks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `shell=True`, pass the whole command as a string:

```
p = subprocess.Popen("ls -l",shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Daniel's point about `shell=True` being dangerous is valid, though.

Comment: Did not know that shell-True needed the command without split... Thanks for this